# Objective C Singleton method not available in Swift Interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton, method-missing

I've been looking for documents of reasons of why a singleton method definition in Objective-C class is not available on the Swift interface on Xcode.

The Objective-C class is defined like this

```
/**
 * A general accessor across the sample App to remove the dependency of QPSLibraryManager from resusable components.
 */
@interface QPSSharedAccessor : NSObject

/**
 * Required by QPSLibraryManager and some UI components.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) QPSApplicationConfiguration *qpsConfiguration;

/**
 * Provides Commands to app
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<QPSAppController> appController;;

/**
 * Shared singleton.
 */
+ (instancetype)sharedAccessor;

/**
 * Returns access to a configuration manager
 */
- (QPSConfigurationManager *)configurationManager;

@end
```

On Swift Interface, its defined like this

```
/**
 * A general accessor across the sample App to remove the dependency of QPSLibraryManager from resusable components.
 */
open class QPSSharedAccessor : NSObject {


    /**
     * Required by QPSLibraryManager and some UI components.
     */
    open var qpsConfiguration: QPSApplicationConfiguration!


    /**
     * Provides Commands to app
     */
    open var appController: QPSAppController!


    /**
     * Returns access to a configuration manager
     */
    open func configurationManager() -> QPSConfigurationManager!
}
```

I'm expected to see the sharedAccessor() singleton method on Swift but it is missing as you can see. Calling the said method on a separate swift file results in a compiler error, saying that the sharedAccessor() method doesn't exist. Converting everything to Swift is not viable btw. Advice on fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I see that `sharedAccessor()` appears to have some special meaning.  Using a different name for it, e.g. `sharedAccessor1()` or `sharedInstance()`, worked for me just fine.  One related observation is that trying to call `sharedAccessor()` when it is NOT part of the interface results in this error: `Type QPSSharedAccessor has no member sharedAccessor`, which makes sense.  However, adding `sharedAccessor()` to the Objective-C code results in:

```
'sharedAccessor()' is unavailable: use object construction 'QPSSharedAccessor()'
```

Opening the error details sheds more light on this:

```
'sharedAccessor()' has been explicitly marked unavailable here (__ObjC.QPSSharedAccessor)
```

Now, renaming the `QPSSharedAccessor` type to something else makes `sharedAccessor()` acceptable, but if the new type name is, for example, `QPSMyClass`, then naming the method `myClass()` becomes a problem!

To work around this strange problem, evidently having to do with compiler internals, obscure method naming conventions, or a bug, you can simply rename the `sharedAccessor()` method to something else.  Alternatively, you can write a wrapper method in C or Objective-C and make it available to Swift via the bridging header.  For example:

```
QPSSharedAccessor * getGlobalQPSSharedAccessor()
{
    return [QPSSharedAccessor sharedAccessor];
}
```

You could also add a category to `QPSSharedAccessor` with a method having a different name and delegating to `sharedAccessor()`.

Also, please see if these references are useful:

[Can't build in Xcode with error "[method] has been explicitly marked unavailable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763641/cant-build-in-xcode-with-error-method-has-been-explicitly-marked-unavailable)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html (see the Singleton section).